# Reducing a figure to a composition of elementary figures

Tags: geometry

I know this question might be rather simple so I apologise in advance.

We are required to find the center of "area" or mass with elementary methods, only using multiplication and summation so no integrals. The problem is I feel like the figure is missing dimensions and I can't seem to break it down into smaller pieces. Any ideas would be appreciated.[image]

Comment: All dimension are given- in terms of the parameter a  so the position of the  center of mass will be given in terms of a.  It looks to me like it can be separated into a quarter disk, of radius 3a/2, a rectangle of width 3a and length 4a, and a semi-circle, of radius 3a/2, with a rectangle of width 3a/2 and length 2a and a circle of radius a **removed**.  I presume you know that to find the center of mass of a combination of different parts, you take a **weighted** average of the centers of masses of each, weighted by their area.  For the "removed" parts, subtract rather than add.

Comment: @user247327 thank you for your time; if you add that as an answer I'd choose it.